# Extending the Windows 8 Messaging Hub

Tags: windows-8, instant-messaging

In Windows 8 the messaging hub provides a single mechanism for sending messages via the Windows Live Messenger and Facebook protocols.

Are there any extension-points available for adding additional protocols/accounts beyond these, so that you could plug in your own chat protocol?

I'd like to create a Steam Chat extension, if possible, but I require a suitable point to extend from first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  There are not any extension points to add functionality to the Messaging hub at this time.

Comment: There are no extension points that everyday developers can access anyway.

Comment: Are there any plans (that we know of) to extend this functionality in the future?